# How to make C function compiled by OpenWatcom return a double in ST(0)?

Tags: c, watcom

The C function

```c
double retfp(void) { return 42; }
```

, when compiled with OpenWatcom C compiler for Linux i386:

```
owcc -blinux -fno-stack-check -fsigned-char -march=i386 -Os -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -mregparm=0 -c -o retfp.owcc.obj retfp.c
```

has code which returns the double in EDX:EAX. However, I want to get it in ST(0) instead, like how GCC does it. Is thiss possible with OpenWatcom, maybe via a command-line flag?

Comment: This seems like a calling convention issue which would be built into the compiler.. But what's wrong if it returns in edx:eax, do you need those two registers ?

Comment: One option I can think of is write a wrapper function in x86 which takes registers edx:eax and puts them into st0 then returns them to the caller. Then all your C functions would return to the wrapper function, hehe

Comment: @Irelia: I need ST(0) for interoperability with code already compiled with other compilers, expecting ST(0). I know that I can write wrapper functions, but I'd prefer a simpler and easier to maintain solution, if available.

Comment: I can accept *doubles are hardwired to be returned in EDX:EAX* as an answer. However, I'm optimistic that I missed a setting somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify calling convention which returns floating point values in ST(0), for example `cdecl`:

```c
double __cdecl retfp(void) {  return 42; }
```

Dissassembler output:

```
Segment: _TEXT BYTE USE32 00000007 bytes
0000                            _retfp:
0000  DD 05 00 00 00 00                 fld             qword ptr L$1
0006  C3                                ret
...
Segment: CONST DWORD USE32 00000008 bytes
0000                            L$1:
0000  00 00 00 00 00 00 45 40                         ......E@
```

Also you can specify default calling convention to `owcc` with `-mabi` flag.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Use `owcc -mabi=cdecl` instead of `owcc -mregparm=0`.

Extending the answer of @dimich:

- The `owcc -mabi=...` and `owcc =mregparm=...` flag values **together** determine the calling convention, and the calling convention determines (e.g.) in which registers values are returned.
- The `owcc -mabi=...` flag corresponds to the `wcc386 -ec...` flag, e.g. `owcc -mabi=cdecl` is the same as `wcc386 -ecc`.
- The `owcc -mregparm=...` flag corresponds to the undocumented (!) `wcc386 -3...` flag, e.g. `owcc -mregparm=0` is the same as `wcc386 -3s`, and `owcc -mregparm=3` is the same as `wcc386 -3r`.
- The default is `owcc -mregparm=3 -mabi=watcall`.
- doubles are returned in EDX:EAX with `owcc -mregparm=0 -mabi=pascal`, `owcc -mregparm=0 -mabi=fortran`, `owcc -mregparm=0 -mabi=watcall`, `owcc -mregparm=0`.
- doubles are returned in ST(0) with `owcc -mregparm=0 -mabi=cdecl`, `owcc -mregparm=0 -mabi=stdcall`, `owcc -mregparm=0 -mabi=fastcall`, `-mregparm=0 -mabi=syscall`, `owcc -mregparm=3`, and also with `owcc -mregparm=3 -mabi=...` (any `-mabi=...` value).